# Disable tool tips of XML files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to know how to disable tool tips in Eclipse when using XML files. I could disable them in java files by deselecting Hover options through Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Hovers and deselecting hover options. I need to know how to do the same for XML editor since I couldn't find such options under XML in eclipse preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the same for XML documents as well, by navigating to **Preferences > XML Files > Editor** and select the **Structured Text Editors** link (refer image below)

[image: XML Editor Preferences]

Next in the **Structured Text Editor** section select the hover tab and you could enable disable hovers as required.

[image: Structured Text Editor]